# fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postgresql

При подключении выкидывает такую ошибку.
что надо изметить в pg_hba.conf, чтобы подключиться к БД ?
Файл:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Как подключаетесь? По хосту? Или через unix-сокет?

Comment: подключаюсь либо по localhost, либо по 127.0.0.1 . результат один

Comment: ну у вас там и сказано, что для всех пользователей при входе по хосту применять md5, требующий пароля. Альтернатива -- вход через unix-сокет. Там пароль не нужен, peer-аутентификация, по пользователю в ОС.

Comment: Вопрос "как подключаетесь" остаётся, потому что вы сейчас для всех локальных подключений инициированных кем угодно разрешаете доступ без пароля.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*no password supplied* можно перевести как *пароль не был предложен*.

вероятно, лучше всё-таки авторизоваться с паролем.

но если очень нужно, и вы осознаёте все риски такого решения, то попробуйте заменить *md5* на *trust*. и не забудьте перезапустить *postgresql* после этого.

Comment: спасибо! помогло.